# Where is it ok to set \arrayrulewidth

Tags: tables

I would like to be able to change border width of cells per cell, or at least, per row. One can do this by changing \arrayrulewidth. But, if I do that at the start of a table row, I get errors.

Starting from:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{centering}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.25\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth}}
one & two \tabularnewline
three & \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.25\textwidth}|}{four} \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\par\end{centering}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Where is it legitimate to place `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}`, so as to alter the width of a particular border - say those around cell four? And do I need any `\global` or similar?

Comment: Please state a use case for what you're trying to accomplish. By the way, I assume you're aware of the fact that changing the widths of the cell borders for adjacent cells is a prescription for (typographic) disaster.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in a `table`-environment because it adds (unwanted) extra space. Instead use `\centering`

Comment: @Mico I am writing a program that writes LaTeX tables. You may well be right, but my job is to let the user do what they want, not to improve their typography!

Comment: `\centering` not `\begin{centering}` (then you don't need `\par`)  There is no supprted way to change arrayrulewidth mid-table  you can use `array` package and `!{\vrule width 2pt}`  instead of `|` for thicker rules

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why do you post correct answers as comments so often?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments usually because I don't have time to post an answer (I was just leaving the building at that point) also if (as here) it's probably a duplicate but i didn't have time to search to find it